# How do I resolve spring configuration property without @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-properties

I'm using Java 8 and Spring Boot. And I'm trying to solve the warning "Cannot resolve configuration property" from IDEA:

[image: Cannot resolve configuration property]
(application.properties)

But for this param I don't have any @ConfigurationProperties class to be handled by the "[spring-boot-configuration-processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata.annotation-processor)"

I'm only using this param like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Value("${some.param}")
private String param;
```

I tried to create de metadata file manually but that didn't solve the problem either.

Does anyone have a tip for this?

This is my Application Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sample"})
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use additional metadata for this. Although it would be nice to automatically generate this from the @Value (or similar) annotation automatically...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#appendix.configuration-metadata.annotation-processor.adding-additional-metadata

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would look like?

Comment: I haven't tested it sorry, I just came across it when I was looking into solving the same issue. Since I don't want to manually write any .json file I decided to instead just live with the warnings.

If I wanted to solve this then I'd consider making a large '@'ConfigurationProperties annotated class with appropriate descriptions via block comments. I can then inject this pojo where needed and essentially not use '@'Value anywhere in my code.